# Value changing when I pass array into function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am passing an array of 64 ints into a function in c. It is not displaying the same value when I print p[1] inside the function versus when i print p[1] outside the function in the main. The output I am getting is "this is p[1]: 0" and "this is p[1] inside the function: 1"

below is the code in the main:

```
for (int i=0; i < 64; i++){
 if (((i+1)%4) == 0){
  int new = ((i+1)/4)-1;
  printf("this is p[1]: %d\n", p[1]);
  gg[new] = getgg(&g, &p, i-3);
  gp[new] = getgp(&p, i-3);
}
}
```

here is my function:

```
int getgg(int (*g)[64], int (*p)[64], int i){
   printf("this is p[1] inside the function: %d\n", *p[1]);
   if((*g[i+3]) || (*p[i+3] && *g[i+2]) || (*p[i+3] && *g[i+2] && *g[i+1]) ||   (*p[i+3] && *p[i+2] && *p[i+1] && *g[i]) ){
return 1;
}
else{
return 0;
 }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Including how `p` is declared.

Comment: probably you mean `(*g)[i+3]` etc. inside the function  , hard to say for sure without the MCVE

Comment: Is this code for the [IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org/)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a huge mess there, you need to get used to pointers!

Ok so your function gets `g` and `p` which are `int *`. What you give them is `&g` and `&p`, where `g` and `p` are also `int *`. So you pass to your function type `int **`.

Also `g[i+3]` is `*(g+i+3)` so lets see what `*g[i+3]` is.

`g` is the address of the address of the first element of your array. `g[i+3]` is `i+3` spots next to the address of the address blah blah blah... so `*g[i+3]` is the content of that!

It's something you probably have no idea about!

Try to pass `g` and `p` instead of `&g` and `&p` and remove all the `*` from your function.

Comment: The function expects `int (*)[64]`, not `int *`.  Also you assert that `g` and `p` (iin `main`) are `int *`, however that is unclear from the question. They could be arrays.

Comment: Oh yes true. Didn't notice the [64] part, might be because of the time and the fatigue. Edited my answer, now it corrects the mistake, however it changes the function a lot.